# Shell functions - non active after command call

Tags: linux, shell

In `~/bin` I have a shell script called `foo`, and in this script, I have the following, and only the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
func(){
   echo this is func
}
```

Now whenever I'm logged on, if I call `foo`, I expect the entire shell script to be ran. That is, after typing `foo` on the command line, there then exists a shell function called `func` that simply echos "this is func". However, this is not the case. Even if I call `foo`, `func` still doesn't exist.

How do I make that function exist? Indeed, I could make an alias in `~/.bashrc`, but let's assume we're only restrained to shell scripts within bin.

EDIT: `foo` is marked executable. I am able to call foo without any problems; that is, if I type `foo`, then I receive no standard error, so I know `foo` was implemented. However, the function `func` within `foo` appears not to be.

Comment: The function *does exist*, but only in the /bin/bash that is spawned by executing your script. When that shell exits, so does the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run a script as a command, it runs in a subprocess, and any changes it makes to the environment have no effect on the original shell process. If you want it to modify the original shell process, you need to `source` it.

```
source ~/bin/foo
```

or

```
. ~/bin/foo
```

If `~/bin` is in your `$PATH` you can simplify this to

```
. foo
```

Comment: Perfect, this worked. The text I'm reading doesn't mention any subprocesses, so this helped a lot. Thank you.

Comment: Every time you run a program from the shell it runs in a new process.

Answer (score -1):

Is `~/bin` in your PATH? Also is `~/bin/foo` marked executable? If not, `chmod +X ~/bin/foo`.

## Edit:

Proper syntax should be as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
func() {
  echo This is func
}
```

Comment: Is the way that you typed it in your question the way that it's typed in the script? If so, you're likely throwing an error. Check my edit for proper syntax.

Comment: Yes, it's exactly as you've typed in your edit. Sorry, I didn't know how to make it to format like that in stackoverflow, but now I do!

Comment: Try running `bash ~/bin/foo`, does this act as expected?

Comment: The problem remains after `bash ~/bin/foo`. Strange. So I am right to expect the function `func` to  exist after `foo` is executed in command line?

Comment: Assuming that the syntax is correct (`{echo` will throw an error, there needs to be a space) and `~/bin` is infact in your PATH variable, yes, it absolutely should work. If running the script directly isn't working either (tested working on my machines) I would assume something is wrong with bash or there's missing information.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'm glad to know that it should work. I'll see what I can find.